# Why does my generics constraint still needs casting?

Tags: c#, generics

Can anyone shed some light as to why calling the 'DoTest1' method below is a problem?

As to why do I need to cast the incoming GridCore object still to the generic type T even though I am specifying that T derives from GridCore with my where T : GridCore?

Thanks

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTest<MyAlbum> mytest = new MyTest<MyAlbum>();
        mytest.DoTest1(new MyAlbum());
        mytest.DoTest2(new MyAlbum());
    }
}

public class GridCore { }

public class MyAlbum : GridCore
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class MyTest<T> where T : GridCore
{
    private List<T> _list = new List<T>();

    public void DoTest1(GridCore ma)
    {
        //_list.Add(ma);        <-- why doesn't this work?
        _list.Add((T)ma);
    }

    public void DoTest2(T ma)
    {
        _list.Add(ma);
    }

}
```

Comment: Because not all `GridCore`'s are `T`s. What if `ma` was some other type derived from `GridCore` and `T` was a different type derived from `GridCore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, because not all `GridCore`'s are `T`'s. All `T`'s are `GridCores` (because of the constraint), not the other way around.

Imagine this:

```
public class MyChicken : GridCore
{
    public string FavouriteColour { get; set; }
}

....

new MyTest<MyAlbum>().DoTest1(new MyChicken());
```

If your code was allowed you'd now have a chicken when you expect an album. Needless to say people trying to listen to music might not get what they expect.

What you probably want is to change the `DoTest1` signature to accept only the `T` that the class deals with:

```
public void DoTest1(T ma)
```

Now, a `MyTest<MyAlbum>` will only accept `MyAlbum`'s to it's `DoTest1` method.

Comment: Thanks for the input George - I actually did have your recommendation in my query (the DoTest2 call).  You are correct with your reasoning though!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting your method to infer that `GridCore` is `T` (*because of the constraint*) then at compile time it can't. That is why you are getting the error.

[Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

> The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method
>   arguments you pass in; it **cannot infer the type parameters only from
>   a constraint** or return value.

Comment: I'm right in thinking that it can't infer that `GridCore` is `T` because it isn't (necessarily), right? `T` is a `GridCore`, but not the other way round.

Comment: There are no constraint for `GridCore`. Constraint is for  `T` and it has some value at compile time. `GridCore  gridcore  = (T)ma;` is ok

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, there is no constraint for GridCore, its for `T`,  My point is it can not consider `GridCore` to be `T` just because of the constraint.

Comment: Thanks for this Habib / Dmitry - interesting line in bold you printed!

Answer (score 0):

```
       private List<T> _list = new List<T>();
```

_list is of Type T, while ma

```
       public void DoTest1(GridCore ma)
```

is of type GridCore.  That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: -1. Please, consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Please provide explanation for you comment.

Comment: I voted -1 for your  answer because you are terribly wrong. That is because you don't know some important things in C#. I provided a link, where you can read about cases, when T can be any type.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly: I'm not sure you're 100% correct here, for me you are muddying the water a bit. What realnero says in his answer is correct. Not all `GridCore`'s are `T`'s. That is the problem. It's precisely because `T` can be any (derived) type that is the problem. Maybe his answer could be fleshed out a bit with an explanation, but personally I don't think it deserves a -1 and isn't "Terribly wrong".

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, I think you are wrong here and better read the msdn article you suggested and also something about OOP.  Next time please explain what you mean about "terribly wrong".

Comment: @realnero Sorry for that, i just misinterpreted your short answer "is of Type T, while ma is of type GridCore. That's why it doesn't work" for not knowing about generics

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly next time read/think twice before commenting like this :)

Answer (score 0):

C# does require the developer to explicitly cast an object to any of its derived types since such a cast could fail at runtime. T is derived from GridCore. So you can write

```
GridCore gridcore = new T();
```

but should cast explicit in

```
T t = (T)new GridCore();
```

Answer (score 0):

`where T: GridCore` means a `T` is a `GridCore`, that is, `GridCore` is the base type or interface of `T`.

But your list is `List<T>`, that is, it's a list of `T` and `T` possibly be a derived class of `GridCore`.

Let we assume that `T` is `DerivedGridCore` and has a field `int X`, then is `GridCore` supposed to have a field `int X`?

Unless you explicitly convert the type(or there's a implicit operator), compiler would not make that assumption, because that convert is not guaranteed.

For a more intuitive thinking, a `Girafe` is an `Animal`, but an `Animal` is not necessarily can only be a `Girafe`; a `Tirget` is either an `Animal`.